# Add markers to Google Map when navigate the map

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a lot of markers (around 3000) in Google Map and they are with icon and advanced details in popup. That is why, map opens very late, **also all markers load very late.** Because I load all markers list from database and display them with foreach loop in one time.

Now I think **to load markers part by part when navigate (slide) the map**.

For example, if I am in *Region1*, I can see markers only in *Region1*, when I navigate (slide) the map to *Region2*, to load only markers in *Region2*

Please, any ideas, sample or link for this. Does Google Maps API has navigate events?

Comment: where/how did you store the details for the markers?

Comment: I store marker details data at database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google website has a page dedicated to this issue with different approaches to improve performance:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

The chapter "Viewport Marker Management" in particular should contain some useful information about how to implement what you describe.

Answer (score 5):

You can register map events for center and zoom level changes then load markers if they are in the current viewport:

```
function loadMarker() {
    // Get the center lat/lng of the map
    var center = map.getCenter();

    // Get the size of the map viewport
    var bounds = map.getBounds(), 
    var cor1 = bounds.getNorthEast(), 
    var cor2 = bounds.getSouthWest(), 
    var cor3 = new google.maps.LatLng(cor2.lat(), cor1.lng()), 
    var cor4 = new google.maps.LatLng(cor1.lat(), cor2.lng()), 
    var width = spherical.computeDistanceBetween(cor1,cor3), 
    var height = spherical.computeDistanceBetween( cor1, cor4);

    // Loop through your markers
    for(var i=0; i < <size of your marker array>; i++) {
        // Get the distance between the center of the map and your markers
        var distanceFromMarker = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, <marker lat/lng>);

        if(distanceFromMarker <= width || distanceFromMarker <= height) {
            <load marker>
        }
    }
}

// Register center and zoom level change events
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', loadMarker);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', loadMarker);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may request the marker-details based on the bounds of the map on demand from the DB(e.g. on bounds_changed) .

Optimally your DB should support [spatial queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)(but it's not required)